# Amasty Reps and Dealers - Magento 1.7

Tags: admin, extensions, adminhtml, forms

I'm using the extension Amasty Reps and Dealers which works beautifully but I want to change the naming convention of somethings.

Because this is an extension I'm unable to find how it inserted into the

AdminPanel --> Customers --> Manage Customers --> Click on a Customer --> Account Information then I want to change the name here from Dealer to Merchant on the left side, right below "Customer Group" and above "Prefix".[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please edit the following file:
Magento_root/app/locale/en_US/Amasty_Perm.csv
and replace the following line:
"Dealer","Dealer"
by the following line:
"Dealer","Merchant"

Comment: Awesome just had to clear my cache and this worked thanks